# Bootstrap + Google Material Design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

When using Bootstraps "Buttons with Dropdowns" template with Google Material Design, I get a text field and a button that are different heights & do not line up.

How it should be: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns

Instead I get this:
[image]

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Go!</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

How would I fix this? I have identified that the form is displayed correctly when GMD is removed from the project.

Comment: By "Google Material Design", are you referring to a specific stylesheet that (in theory) implements the guidelines?

Comment: Your HTML says `Go!` but your image shows `GO!`... don't lie to us, you're hiding something :P

Comment: Are you using http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Bootstrap Material Design doesn't take into account Input Groups, but you can customize it to fit your needs. See example.

```js
$.material.init()
```

```css
.container .input-group .form-control {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.container .input-group-btn .btn-custom {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #009688;
}
.container .input-group .form-control:focus,
.container .input-group .form-control:hover {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: none;
}
.container .input-group-btn .btn-custom:focus,
.container .input-group-btn .btn-custom:hover {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
/*Standard*/

.input-group-btn .btn-custom-og {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: 0;
}
.input-group-btn .btn-custom-og:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}
.input-group .form-control.standard {
  height: 40px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
}
.input-group .form-control.standard:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/ripples.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-custom">Go!</button>
    </span>

  </div>

  <hr>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control standard" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-custom-og">Go!</button>
    </span>

  </div>

</div>
<hr>
```